# How to add new menu item in Top Navigation in DivShot?

Tags: divshot

I'm using DivShot to build a mockup. However it seems that I'm unable to figure out how to add new menu item besides two menu item in top navigation.

Any idea?

Comment: Same issue.  Can't add a button to the nav bar and have it be centered.

Comment: There is no help available in DivShot. Instead I started using Pencil which is an awesome piece of software to get job done.